# no such file or directory: '__entitlements' in xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

i am getting this error while building the app:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '__entitlements'

using `Xcode 8.2`.

Comment: Added entitlements file and keychain sharing is On.Still getting same error.

Answer (score 23):

I faced the same issue, I fixed it by removing everything except the `$(inherited)` in `Other Linker Flags` from Build settings.

Comment: Can confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer saved me. Thanks a lot. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 16):

This can happen if you have a dangling `-framework` line in your `Other Linker Flags` build settings, without a framework following it. Just remove it and it should work.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you, sir!